# Missing number in a table

Tags: mathematics

**Table.**

```
      3
  ? ? ?
    3 1
  2 1 1
2 3 1 1
```

What number is missing and why?

Comment: I have an answer but I'm confused by the number of missing digits... just to make sure, there are *three* digits we're looking for?

Comment: Red herring...?

Comment: Hmm... probably then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is (thanks to Engima for the prompt)

> $007$

Reasoning

> It's easier to ignore the formatting and consider the number formed by each line $3, ?, 31, 211, 2311$.
>  Taking $1$ from each of these gives a more familiar sequence $2, ?, 30, 210, 2310$ which some people will recognise immediately as the product of the first $n$ primes (also called Euclid numbers, which feature in Euclid's proof of infinite primes).
>  The product of the first $2$ primes is $6$ so the missing element is $6+1=7$ or $007$ if we wish to fill the question marks.

Comment: Nice! The question marks give 007. You may also check out the mathematician Euclid

Comment: @Enigma Ah, I see.

Comment: Lol nice, I was too unsure to post this answer. The single 3 ( with no 0's made me doubt this)